# PHP Get values from Multiple form arrays

Tags: php, forms

I have the following form, how can i get the data from multiple[] arrays in the form and combine them into 3 data sets eg name[], quantity[], unit[]

```
    <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />

<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" />

                    <select name="unit[]" >
                        <option value="">--Unit--</option>
                        <option value="g">g</option> 
                    </select>

                   <select name="unit[]" >
                        <option value="">--Unit--</option>
                        <option value="g">g</option> 
                    </select>

                    <select name="unit[]" >
                        <option value="">--Unit--</option>
                        <option value="g">g</option> 
                    </select>
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and you will see the structure of your post data

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php answers your question.

> Example #1 A simple HTML form
>
> ```html
> > 
> > 
> > 
> >     <form action="action.php" method="post">
> >      <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
> >      <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
> >      <p><input type="submit" /></p>
> >     </form>
> > 
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> There is nothing special about this form. It is a straight HTML form
>   with no special tags of any kind. When the user fills in this form and
>   hits the submit button, the action.php page is called. In this file
>   you would write something like this:
>
> Example #2 Printing data from our form
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
> >     You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> A sample output of this script may be:
>
> Hi Joe. You are 22 years old.
>
> Apart from the htmlspecialchars() and (int) parts, it should be
>   obvious what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Do var_dump($_POST) to view all results.

in $_POST['name'] (or quantity or unit) u have an array with 3 results.